# Swift - Get XML attrributes

Tags: swift, xml

I am trying to loop through the following example XML using CheatyXML

```
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.16.0">
<indexes lastModified="1524417436798" ignoredArticles="The El La Los Las Le Les">
<index name="E">
<artist id="14" name="Editors"/>
</index>
<index name="K">
<artist id="27" name="Kings Of Leon"/>
</index>
</indexes>
</subsonic-response>
```

I have an artist object that contains the artist name and artist ID. My goal is to populate an array of Artists with the relevent information.

I am struggling to loop through the XML correctly though, the code below returns the same artist (Editors) twice. Please help.

```
func getArtists()->[Artist]{
    var artist = [Artist]()
    //GET SAVED SUBIFY INFORMATION
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let server:String = defaults.string(forKey: "Server")!
    let username:String = defaults.string(forKey: "Username")!
    let password:String = defaults.string(forKey: "Password")!

    //PARSE XML TO GET VALUE
    let url = URL(string:"\(server)/rest/getIndexes?u=\(username)&p=\(password)&v=1.12.0&c=Subify")
    let parser:CXMLParser! = CXMLParser(contentsOfURL:url!)
    for element in parser["indexes"] {
        var artistAdd = Artist()
        artistAdd.id = parser["indexes"]["index"]["artist"].attribute("id").string!
        artistAdd.name = parser["indexes"]["index"]["artist"].attribute("name").string!
        dump(artistAdd)

    }
    //RETURN VALUE
    dump(artist)
    return artist

}
```

This is the library I'm using https://github.com/lobodart/CheatyXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, you define `element` as the variable that contains the current element on each iteration:

```
for element in parser["indexes"] {
```

...but then inside the loop, you don't use `element`, you go back to the root of the document, so the library has no way of knowing which element you want, and defaults to giving you the first one:

```
artistAdd.id = parser["indexes"]["index"]["artist"].attribute("id").string!
```

I think all you need to do is actually use your loop variable in the loop:

```
artistAdd.id = element["artist"].attribute("id").string!
```

Comment: When I did do that I did element["index"]["artist"] for some reason, idiot!! Thank you very much works perfect.